# tmux: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5

Tags: upgrade, tmux

After upgrade ubuntu 16 to 18, I got this error when executing tmux:

**tmux: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.0.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

and here's result when I execute `ldd $(which tmux)`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd9878a000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f5588dfc000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f5588bd2000)
libevent-2.0.so.5 => not found
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f55889b7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f55885c6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5588fff000
```

I got tmux by following [instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/tmux/tmux). It worked on Ubuntu 16.

```
$ apt-cache policy tmux

Installed: (none)
Candidate: 2.6-3
Version table:
    2.6-3 500
    500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Tmux under Bionic (18.04) requires a later version of libevent (2.1) than you mention (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tmux).  Where did you get your tmux as it doesn't match the bionic version of tmux  (*your version does match the requirements for xenial's tmux https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tmux*) maybe check your `apt-cache policy tmux`

Comment: I got tmux by follow instuction  on github  ( https://github.com/tmux/tmux ) 

It was works on ubuntu 16. here's result **apt-cache policy tmux ** 


```Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.6-3
  Version table:
     2.6-3 500
        500 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: ie. you installed it yourself, you agreed to maintain it yourself (*as apt packaging doesn't know about it & thus can't maintain-upgrade it*) and you need to manage the upgrades yourself (as you didn't install the auto-maintained version).  You'll need to recompile for your existing installation (you compiled (*make; make install*) it for 16.04 and not 18.04) or remove it, and install the Ubuntu one (which won't need these steps on future release-upgrades).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As *@guiverc* commented - both [`tmux`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tmux) and [`libevent`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libevent-2.1-6) are well-packaged on Ubuntu Bionic Beaver 18.04 LTS (and other versions).

You should remove locally-installed `tmux` with one of the following methods:

- Check version of locally-installed `tmux`:

  ```
  tmux -V # or from `man tmux`
  ```

  Then clone this version from its github repository, compile it again and run

  ```
  sudo make uninstall
  ```
- Simply remove your self-installed `tmux` with

  ```
  sudo rm $(which tmux)
  ```

  Note: running `sudo rm $(which tmux)` looks safe because of the fact that even official package [do not have shipped other binaries or libraries](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/tmux/filelist).

And install package from repository:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

Comment: Self-compiled packages are better removed with `sudo make uninstall`, if available (not all source packages provide it).

Comment: I agree, but we do not have any guarantee that OP has not removed original source directory. Edited my answer.

Comment: The source directory can always be re-obtained. ;)

Comment: @fkraiem thank you for great idea. I edited the answer again.

Comment: what if you're not root?

Comment: This answer is no good if your not root, cant sudo apt-get anything. Have to compile all from source in home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Tmux under Bionic (18.04) requires a later version of libevent (2.1) than you mention (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/tmux). I asked "where did you get your tmux as it doesn't match the bionic version of tmux" noting your version does match the requirements for xenial's tmux (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tmux) suggesting check your

```
apt-cache policy tmux
```

You then told me you installed it yourself, meaning you (possibly *unwittingly* or *unknowingly*)  agreed to maintain it yourself as apt packaging doesn't know about it & thus can't maintain-upgrade it. Thus you need to manage the upgrades yourself (as you didn't install the auto-maintained version).

Your two main choices I see are :-

(1) you need to recompile for your existing installation (following the instructions in the documented you used the first time, eg. `make; make install..`) as your prior compile was done for Ubuntu 16.04 and not 18.04.

(2) remove it, and install the Ubuntu one using normal `apt` tools. This has the advantage of always having automatic security updates, plus will be updated in future release-upgrades (*even if this is 20.04*)  See @N0rbert's answer & thread's comments for clues as to removal

*[these notes were comments converted to an answer]*

Comment: You’re welcome! For next time, you should mention me in a comment on the question as the notification does not work here where I haven’t commented/edited yet. You’re lucky I’ve come across the question again. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This solved my issue:

```
sudo apt install libevent-dev
```

Comment: `pacman -S libevent` works for me in arch linux.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 20 and the best options for me was to compile from source.

Sources are on GitHub: https://github.com/tmate-io/tmate

Download, compile, and install with the following steps:

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/tmate-io/tmate.git
cd tmate
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

A few dependencies are required. The Ubuntu package names are:
git-core build-essential pkg-config libtool libevent-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev automake libssh-dev libmsgpack-dev

You can find the official documentation here: https://tmate.io/

Answer (score 0):

For me upgrade debian 9 to debian 10 cause this error

Installing `libevent-2.1-6` solve issue.

`apt install libevent-2.1-6`

After that here is output of `ldd $(which tmux)`

```
$ ldd $(which tmux)
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe6435f000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f0fca4c9000)
libutempter.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutempter.so.0 (0x00007f0fca2c6000)
libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f0fca297000)
libevent-2.1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevent-2.1.so.6 (0x00007f0fca041000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f0fca029000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0fc9e66000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0fc9e43000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0fca57e000)
```